# Install *.domain.com SSL certificate in openSUSE Leap 15.2

Tags: opensuse, ssl

I have the budle, the .key/.pem and everything else. How should I install it on the local machine?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your question is unclear. Where to place the certificate and private key depends on what software (Apache HTTP, Nginx, Tomcat, etc.) will be utilizing the certificate for SSL/TLS encryption. Changes to the software configuration from default could also affect where the files would be installed. Please edit your question and include these details.

Answer (score 0):

The private key cert goes into `/etc/ssl/key` and the public cert goes into `/etc/ssl/crt`, although these are quite arbitrary. If the system does not have the root certs, then put them into `/usr/share/pki/trust/anchors` and call `update-ca-certificates` and once done, you should see the new root cert under `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

Comment: In 15.4 there is no directory `/etc/ssl/key/`. From where does the directory recommendation originate from?

Comment: @JariTurkia Like I said, they are arbitrary, they could be anywhere as long as the application can read them. When you configure your app, you point them to wherever you place them. The `key` & `crt` directories is where I am fairly certain the system would place them, although `private` is also a candidate.

Comment: Most Linux distros have dedicated directory for X.509 / PKI. I find it odd, Leap doesn''t.